# VS2019 Обозреватель объектов/Сводка - русский язык IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 => Вид => Обозреватель объектов

Возможно ли настроить сводку на RU язык ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/localized-intellisense

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это машинный перевод ?

Comment: Этот вопрос надо адресовать Microsoft, их официальные пакеты. Предположу, что частично да, частично нет, ведь в .Framework вполне нормальный перевод, не? Скорей всего взяли большую часть оттуда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EvgeniyZ дал исчерпывающий комментарий, но почему то не оформляет как ответ.

**Установка локализованных файлов IntelliSense для .NET**

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/localized-intellisense

Проделав все шаги, получил это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я всё равно советую использовать и учить английский. В локализации могут быть ошибки, и в разработке под .NET без английского языка все равно никак.

Comment: Ответу плюс, но я подписываюсь под пожеланием учить английский (а для того -- сразу включать английский интерфейс)

Comment: Как в самом языке программирования разберусь, сразу переключу xD
- А то такое себе и учиться язык программирования и учить английский.

Comment: @Алексей и каково будет ваше удивление, когда спустя какое-то время вы увидитие исключение на английском и не поймете, что оно значит, потому что всё это время вы видели только кривой русский перевод. Оставьте руссификацию студии школьникам. Если вы настроены серьезно стать разработчиком, английский надо учить вперед шарпа. А шарп вам в этом как раз поможет своими сообщениями на английском. Если вы так, сдать зачёт и забыть про шарп как про страшный сон - то может руссификатор для вас и нормальное решение.

Comment: @aepot неее, проф. разработчиком уже поздно становиться, мне так, пару RU книг по языку прочитать и чуть чуть от нечего делать поиграться.

Comment: Ну тогда может и без разницы.

Comment: @aepot но то что исключения переводятся, действительно не удобно) - Хотелось бы только сводку.

Comment: Поковыряйтесь в файлах докализации. Думаю, можно и отдельно установить.

Comment: @aepot думаю что точно можно, например из xml EN в RU куски exeption переставить - но ща не осилю, может как ни будь потом и для себя и на благо общества xD