# Всплывающие подсказки в visual studio, как сменить язык

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

visual studio 2022, всплывающие подсказки на английском (не критично). На YouTube у блогеров все написано на русском. Посмотрел советы в интернете, пробовал language packs для net framework, не помогает. Может это в старых версиях только было ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дополнительные языковые пакеты ставятся в инсталляторе Студии.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287184/220553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: В комментарии @EvgeniyZ отправил рабочее решение, оказывается перевод присутствует: [ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287184/220553](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287184/220553)

Ваши подсказки на русском, просто документация для данных методов прописана на английском. Вам так же стоит установить Русский языковой пакет через Visual Studio Installer:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. : Это вряд ли поможет, потому что НИКТО не будет писать документацию базовых методов для разных языков

EDIT: У меня они так же отсутствуют. Опять же - подсказки к использованию методов прописанны внутри библиотек .NET, которые как раз и используются для взаимодействия с коносолью, а делать систему перевода для документации библиотек - слишком сложно и почти бесполезно, ведь никто не хочет прописывать документацию на всех языках для своих библиотек. При этом обычно документация прописывается прямо внутри файла с кодом с помощью специальной разметки, и с переводом всё это становится слишком неудобным

Comment: Обновил, все тоже самое. Не судьба значит)