# Как переключить язык подсказок Visual Studio при работе в чужом проекте на русский язык

Tags: c#

Периодически в ходе обучения выполняю учебные практические задания, которые представляют собой проекты, в которых нужно написать какие-либо классы или методы. Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда в этих проектах все подсказки IntelliSens для методов и прочего оказываются на английском, хотя когда я работаю в своих проектах подсказки на русском.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно переключить язык подсказок в этих проектах? Русская локализация у меня очевидно установлена.

P.S. Про необходимость учить английский в курсе, давайте воздержимся от дискуссии на эту тему.

Comment: "Подсказки" не являются "переключаемым" параметром, они выводятся сразу на конкретном языке, который заложен в SDK. То, что у вас некоторые проекты имеют английские подсказки, говорит скорей всего о том, что это не .NET Framework (устаревший тип) проект, а современный .NET. Как поставить локализацию для .NET написано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287184/220553), но учтите, .NET5 является последним локализированным (сейчас .NET8)! Так что, да, стоит "учить английский" и не искать альтернатив.

Comment: Видимо, это не всегда так. Потому что подсказки в моих проектах на русском (я говорю об одних и тех же подсказках, разумеется). Ладненько, будем привыкать. Спасибо!

Comment: Это всегда так, независимо от кода. Пожалуйста, научитесь определять на чем написан проект, и поймите разницу между `.NET Framework` и `.NET`. Еще раз повторю - "подсказки" зависят от `SDK`, от того, что вы (или студия) качаете и устанавливаете для программирования. В `.NET Framework` по умолчанию идет **та локализация, которая стоит у вас в системе**, в проектах написанных на `.NET` по умолчанию **используется английский язык**, а начиная с .NET6 и вовсе перевод перестали выпускать. Так что, ПКМ по проекту - свойства - "Целевая платформа"/"Целевая раб. среда" вам в помощь.

Comment: свойства - "Целевая платформа"/"Целевая раб. среда" - что-то не нахожу у себя в студии подобных или похожих пунктов... Там должна быть информация о том, на чем написан проект?

Comment: Да, там пишется версия `.NET` или `.NET Framework`. Повторю, это два разных фреймворка.

Comment: Про то что они разные я в курсе, просто пока учусь с использованием .NET Framework, т.к. в учебном курсе используется он. А вот пункты эти в студии у себя, к сожалению, не вижу...

Comment: Ну... Значит вы либо очень невнимательны, либо у вас очень древняя студия, ибо эти [настройки](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2022#change-the-target-framework) там есть и уже довольно давно.

Comment: Получилось, с 100-го раза) Спасибо за помощь!